# Running Java Program from Command-line

Tags: java

I downloaded a java program that consists of two folders src and classes containing the source files and class files respectively. Now, the src and classes folders contain a several nested sub-folders wherein the last sub-folder contains the source and class files respectively. More precisely, the path to a source and class file is src/edu/univ/.java and classes/edu/univ/.class. Given that the file containing the main function is Main.java, how can I run this program from command-line.

I have tried:

```
 java  src/edu/univ/Main but I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: src/edu/univ/Main
```

I have also tried:
     java src.edu.univ.Main but I encounter a similar error

Comment: try `java edu.univ.Main` you have to use the fully qualified name of the class.

Comment: The `src` folder contains the Java source files. The executable clases are in `classes/edu/...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the root of the project:

```
java -cp classes edu.univ.Main
```

This tells the JRE that the `classes` directory is the root of your package hierarchy. The JRE will load packages from there, following the directory/package naming hierarchy.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: clean this up for colon seperated paths

Comment: @AmirAfghani Irrelevant for the OP at this time.